Grounding PV solar, battery and load
I have simple diy solution for solar system. The system is build using esp32, 2x ina266, ads1115 and acs758. The esp is powered from usb 5v (stepdown from battery) and 3v3 is then distributed into all the modules mentioned above. Same for GND. There will be 3 inputs terminals and one output. 1 input for battery plus pole, one for minus pole and 2 from shunt. The second same as for battery but on load side. And the third will be for PV (2x input and 2x output).
My question is if I can connect all the minus poles (battery, load and solar panels) together and then also connect all the modules gnd pin to this minus bus too.

Is there any risk here?
Ps.: will add the schema if required, but right now the question is simple, connecting all the modules GND and PV-, B- and LOAD- together and what can happen.

Please draw a block diagram or schematic.

@winny thanks, I added basic schematic with power nets

What's PV input?

Photovoltaic input - solar panels. Around 36V and max 13A.

A solar panel have light as input and only electrical output.

My mistake. This scheme is representing that cables from solar panels are reaching “PV input” srew terminals and then “PV output” is where new cables are connected which are then connected to the next device e.g. to MPPT controller.

Ok. A bit confusing way to draw it in a schematic. I would use a photodiode symbol and just bridge your "input" and "output". Also, ideally all inputs to the left, outputs to right, positive voltages point up, negative and ground pointing down.

Sorry. No schematic expert. But my question remains. Can I mix all minus poles (battery, pv, load) together?

Depends. Do you have anything connected do a different ground or is everything but your USB connection floating?

No ground yet. The USB is using battery (see battery input) but separate small circuit which is just stepdown from 12V to 5V. But mine main concern is PV here. As I am not 100% sure how it works.

Are the loads grounded or floating?

Floating, the base system is off-grid solar system.

If you don’t have any loads with ground reference, you should be fine to bind them all on your board as drawn.
